# Run a powershell script from one computer to the next

Tags: powershell

I already have code written to connect to another computer in my house and pull music files from the C drive. However, I am trying to find out how to keep this code, but modify it in a way that I can use it to run code on the second computer, then save it to a text file.

```
foreach ($server in Get-Content .\serverList.txt){
    psexec \\$server -u username-p password cmd /c dir c:\*.mp3 /s > c:\Powershell\$server.txt
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by second computer here? so you want to copy a set of items from the list of  computers to the second computer??

Answer (score 0):

You could write a book on PowerShell Remoting (several people have) but it's reasonably straightforward.

On both computers run `Enable-PSRemoting` to configure all the settings. Then on the originating computer (the one making the remote call) run `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value '*'` (if you are security conscious replace the * with the IP of the remote PC).

Then you can run the all-powerful `Invoke-Command` to do all sorts of awesome stuff remotely. Unless you're on a domain or there's an identical user on the remote PC you'll need to provide credentials which means either prompting for them or saving them, but if I go into too much detail we'll both be here all day. Pretty easy to find the answers on Google.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
foreach ($server in Get-Content .\serverList.txt) {
    Invoke-Command $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem C:\*.mp3 -Recurse } | Out-File C:\Powershell\$server.txt
}
```